# Elixir/Phoenix - trouble updating belongs_to association after it has been set

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an app in which a user can belong to a group. Users and groups can be created separately, and a user can be added to a group later on.

The code below works fine the first time a user is added to a group:

**User Model**

```js
use Ecto.Schema
import Ecto.Changeset

schema "users" do
  field :email, :string
  field :description, :string
  field :deleted, :boolean, default: false
  belongs_to :group, Admin.Group, foreign_key: :group_id, on_replace: :update

  timestamps()
end

def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:code, :user_email, :description, :created_at, :deleted])
  |> validate_required([:code, :user_email, :created_at,])
end
```

**User Controller**

```js
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "data" => data = %{"type" => "users", "attributes" => _user_params, "relationships" => relationships}}) do
  user = Repo.get!(User, id) |> Repo.preload :group
  group = Repo.get_by!(Group, id: data["relationships"]["group"]["data"]["id"])
  changeset = User.changeset(user, Params.to_attributes(data)) |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:group, group)
  case Repo.update(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      render(conn, "show.json-api", data: user)
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(:errors, data: changeset)
  end
end
```

The data attribute for the above looks like this:

```js
%{"attributes" => %{"description" => nil, "inserted_at" => "2017-12-01T14:20:58.423Z",
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-11T10:36:24.073Z",
    "email" => "test@gmail.com"}, "id" => "292",
  "relationships" => %{"group" => %{"data" => %{"id" => "1",
        "type" => "groups"}}}, "type" => "users"}
```

The problem is that if I try and change the group that that user belongs to, the update function returns `200 OK`, but the group does not change.

Checking the output of the data variable shows that the group id is different in the request payload.

```js
%{"attributes" => %{"description" => nil, "inserted_at" => "2017-12-01T14:20:58.423Z",
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-11T10:36:24.073Z",
    "email" => "test@gmail.com"}, "id" => "292",
  "relationships" => %{"group" => %{"data" => %{"id" => "2",
        "type" => "groups"}}}, "type" => "users"}
```

Why would the changeset not recognize the updated group id?

Comment: What's the query that's logged to the console when the update route is called?

Comment: `[debug] Processing with Server.Admin.UserController.update/2
  Parameters: %{"data" => %{"attributes" => %{"description" => nil, "inserted_at" => "2017-12-01T14:20:58.423Z", "updated_at" => "2017-12-11T10:36:24.073Z", "email" => "test@gmail.com"}, "id" => "292", "relationships" => %{"group" => %{"data" => %{"id" => "2", "type" => "groups"}}}, "type" => "users"}, "id" => "292"}
  Pipelines: [:admin_auth]`

Comment: I meant the SQL query when you run `Repo.update`.

Comment: This is the update query when updating the user for the first time ` [debug] QUERY OK db=1.0ms UPDATE "users" SET "group_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "id" = $3 [2, {{2017, 12, 11}, {14, 14, 12, 84337}}, 288]`

This does not happen at all when trying to change the group later.

Comment: Certain. If I log the changeset in the controller it returns `#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: Admin.License<>,  valid?: true>`.

Comment: Could it have something to do with adding `on_replace: :update` to the definition of **belongs_to** in the model? Without this, I get a runtime error when trying to update the second time: `** (RuntimeError) you are attempting to change relation :group of Admin.User but the :on_replace option of this relation is set to :raise.`

Comment: Might be. I've never used `on_replace` and don't know exactly what the different options do. Maybe someone else who knows will chime in.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the incorrect value for `on_replace` in the model. It needed to be `nilify` instead of `update`.

```js
belongs_to :group, Admin.Group, foreign_key: :group_id, on_replace: :nilify
```